# Linux can't mount a CIFS share with comma in path using /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, cifs

I'm having problems mounting a CIFS network drive for use in an application I develop/maintain.  The share path has a folder in it named `, Employees` as in `Company/, Employees/Some data` (the mapped folder is on a Windows domain).

I had to escape the spaces already with the octal `\040`.  The octal `\054` for comma does not work - I still get an error.  After looking at `kern.log`, I see it is interpreting the comma literally and breaking the path:

> ```
> Nov 21 11:15:58 dashboard-prod kernel: [669753.128303] CIFS: Unknown mount option " Employees/Some data"
> ```

It seems that it is ending the path there and expecting what followed the comma to be a path option.

Here's the line in fstab:

```
//path/to/share/, Employees/   /local/path  cifs    defaults,password=foo,sec=ntlm,iocharset=utf8,username=bar   0    0
```

When I attempt to quote the path (hoping it would escape the comma properly) it does escape the comma properly, but then I get:

> ```
> mount.cifs: bad UNC ('//path/to/app/, Employees/folder')
> ```

Comment: Have you tried to put some quote around your path?

Comment: when i try to quote the path, it gives me another error.  i assumed it was not liking the double quotes.  am i supposed to quote both paths together?  i was only quoting the one.

Comment: juste the first path continning your special characters. and you say that you've tried //path/to/share/\054\040Employees/ already? what is the new error now?

Comment: yes I have tried using the octals as you describe them.  when I do that I get "Unknown mount option" above.  when I try just quoting the path, it does translate the path name properly, but then the error it gives me is "mounts.cifs:  bad UNC"

Comment: Can you make it work from the CLI, using *mount -t cifs ...*?

Comment: Tried using the mount -t cifs CLI syntax, and the output is telling me invalid parameter, kern.log gives exit/return code -22

Comment: Have you resolved this issue now?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a proxy app that had to observe file and user permissions and handled mounts from several servers. Users like "," a bit too much.

So I worked around this with the following:

(Let's use the path in the example - '//path/to/app/, Employees/folder')

1. Create a temporary mount directory, i.e. /root/TMP_123)

   mkdir -p /root/TMP_123
2. Mount the share at the root, that usually doesn't contain any trash (in this case, it's //path/to)

   mount -t cifs "//path/to" "/root/TMP_123" -o username=xxxx,password=yyyy,domain=zzzz.local,vers=3.0,nocase
3. Create a symlink to the original content, by combining the rest of the share name after the root path with the mount point, like so:

   ln -s "/root/TMP_123/app/, Employees/folder" "/root/TMP_123-LNK"

After that, your content is accessible via /root/TMP_123-LNK

I haven't tested the actual commands, they're transcripted over here from my original code.

After the code runs, I just run some garbage collection (unmount -f -l /root/TMP_123, then delete every symlink and empty dir older than 10 days or so). Something along the lines of this:

```
find /root/TMP_* -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime +10 -exec rmdir {} \;
find /root/TMP_* -maxdepth 1 -ctime +10 -type l -delete
```

Please not, I intentionally avoid rm -rf, because if a mountpoint doesn't "disarm", e.g. umount fails, then you could recursively blow away that share. rmdir on the other hand will just fail and you can catch the error. Same thing with the other line. Together with maxdepth, it should not disturb stuff that stays mounted for any reason...

Hope this puts someone on the right track if nothing else helps...